Runtime Error Hangup(SIGHUP) for recursion solution to sum of series problem
Problem:
Given an int N, calculate the sum of series 13+23+33+43...... till the nth term using recursion (Link to problem)
Implemented Solution in Python:
#User function Template for python3

class Solution:
    def sumOfSeries(self,n):
        #code here
        if n>0:
            return (n*n*n) + self.sumOfSeries(n-1)
        else:
            return 0
            
#{ 
 # Driver Code Starts
#Initial Template for Python 3

if __name__=='__main__':
    t=int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        N=int(input())
        ob=Solution()
        print(ob.sumOfSeries(N)) 
# } Driver Code Ends

The solution works for small inputs but is giving the above error of large values like 18468
I am unable understand the meaning of the error and what is causing it
I attempted to solve the same problem using recursion in C++ and it is not presenting any error
C++ Solution:
//{ Driver Code Starts
// Initial template for C++
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// } Driver Code Ends
// User function template for C++

class Solution {
  public:
    long long sumOfSeries(long long n) {
        // code here
        if (n==1) 
            return 1;
        else
            return (n*n*n)+sumOfSeries(n-1);
    }
};

//{ Driver Code Starts.
int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        long long N;
        cin >> N;
        Solution ob;
        cout << ob.sumOfSeries(N) << "\n";
    }
}
// } Driver Code Ends


typically, you'll get that signal when - the program was killed (?someone sent the signal), the terminal session it was running in was closed, you can trap this, check out the signal module. on my mac (i7) i get a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded (when attempting 999 terms ... )

The challenge you link to nowhere says you should do this with recursion. On the contrary, it expects a O(1) solution.

@trincot Yes, I had earlier formed an iterative solution for the same and wanted to try out a recursive solution but felt lazy making the test cases. Thank you for the explanation. I really appreciate the O(1) solution as well.

@ticktalk Yes, I tried the same on VS code and it showed the same exception, it seems the test case was too large for the recursive solutiom

The online judge host closes the terminal as the Python code takes too much time to complete.
This is not unexpected. Python code generally runs slower than C++, which explains why it could happen to the Python code and not to the similar C++ code.
Note how the challenge has not suggested that you should solve this with recursion. As n is given to be in the range up to 50000, you should reject the idea to apply recursion here. Moreover, the challenge asks to implement a solution with O(1) time complexity.
Here is a hint on how to do that:

 n-th triangular number squared.

If this is not enough to write a O(1) solution, here is a spoiler:

 return (n*(n+1)//2)**2

